# Random URL, Single content

Tags: spring-mvc, url, jakarta-ee, web

I'm currently developing an app that generates a URL for a certain number of Subscribers. That has the same content. For example a web page with an image in it.

The URL pattern can be like this http://host:XXXX/foo/randomNumbers
I'm planning to have 7 random numbers. That won't repeat for each subscribers.

I'm currently using Java with SpringMVC for this one. Hope you can help me I'm currently stuck with generating the URLs with the same content.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate URL any way you like but you have some static aspects:

e.g.

```
String staticPart = "http://www.yoursite.com/foo/"

//randomly generate the integer number and store in variable (e.g. ranNum)

String finalURL = staticPart + Integer.toString(ranNum)
```

That way your user gets randomly generated url.

Below is method for accessing a randomly generated URL:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo/{id}")
public ModelAndView returnView(@PathVariable int id)
```

I would on top of this store the randomly generated URL for the user and then in the returnView method check if its legitimate.

Content doesn't change that way only url and is made unique to a user.

Is this going to meet your requirement?